# hide image when I select one & show related div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hi I am new in web development, 
I want something similar to this site http://www.ezmetrology.com/.
you can see there are some device images on car's body, so when you mouse over one device it shows the details in a div content of the related device. what I want is when I mouseover one device from the car it should hide the rest of the devices.
is that possible?

please help

thank you

Comment: Where is your code so far? Anything is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example. Hover over item1 and item2 and they change their content

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.clickButtons').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().toggleClass("vis");
  $("div.textC").attr('style','visibility:hidden;')
     var index = $("li").index(this); $("div.textC").eq(index).attr('style','visibility:visible;')
});
  $('.clickButtons').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).siblings().toggleClass("vis");
});
});
```

```css
div#blueOne p{
  color:blue;
}
div#redOne p{
  color:red;
}
div#redOne{
  visibility:hidden; 
}
.textC p{
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  width:60%;

}
.imageC{
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:20px;
  height:90px;
}

.clickButtons{
  cursor:pointer;
  width:100px;
  background-color:grey;
  margin:5px;
}
.clickButtons.vis{
  visibility:hidden;
}
.textCon{
  position:relative;
  margin-top:40px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="clickButtons">Item 1</li>
    <li class="clickButtons">Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  <div class="textCon">
  <div id="blueOne" class="textC"><p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p><img class="imageC" src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/2/2a/Nature-a.jpg/240px-Nature-a.jpg"/></div>
    <div id="redOne" class="textC"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy..</p><img class="imageC" src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Anuja, this really helps but just one more thing, when you mouseover on Item 1, is that possible to hide the "Item 2" and same for opposite. thank you once again.

Comment: sorry, I dont get you comment. do you mean the text "item 2" and "item 1"

Comment: yes, Item 1 & Item 2, so when you mouseover "Item 1" it should show the Item 1 related div but also hide "Item 2" text. same for the opposite

Comment: could you please write the code in javascript, i mean same jquery code to javascript please

Comment: that would be too long and complex. for example toggleclass would become 3 lines long. and some other functions are long too. it would become even more complex when you will add more variables while implementing in real web page